# Compiler cannot find EXE file

Tags: c#

I am trying to compile a solution in Visual Studio and get the following errors.  What could be the cause?

All references are properly set.

> Error 4   Metadata file 'c:\users\faneela\documents\visual studio
>   2010\Projects\PL\DAL\bin\Debug\DAL.exe' could not be found
>   Error 5   Metadata file 'C:\Users\Faneela\documents\visual studio
>   2010\Projects\PL\DLL\bin\Debug\DLL.exe' could not be found
>   Error 3   Metadata file 'c:\users\faneela\documents\visual studio
>   2010\Projects\PL\DO\bin\Debug\DO.exe' could not be found
>   Error 2   Metadata file 'C:\Users\Faneela\documents\visual studio
>   2010\Projects\PL\DO\bin\Debug\DO.exe' could not be found
>   Error 6   Metadata file 'C:\Users\Faneela\documents\visual studio
>   2010\Projects\PL\DO\bin\Debug\DO.exe' could not be found
>   Error 7   Metadata file 'c:\users\faneela\documents\visual studio
>   2010\Projects\PL\main\bin\Debug\main.exe' could not be found
>   Error 1   Program 'C:\Users\Faneela\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2010\Projects\PL\DO\obj\x86\Debug\DO.exe' does not contain a static
>   'Main' method suitable for an entry point

Comment: A tip: When getting compile errors like this, find the first error and fix that, then recompile. You are creating an executable file (maybe you have a library project set to output a console app?), that doesn't have an entry point (main). Either you have the wrong build settings, or you haven't properly defined the `Main` method (and yes, it **is case sensitive**). The other errors here are related to metadata files which leads me to believe you have the `DO` project set as a reference in another project.

Comment: exe file is actually not being created ... i personally checked it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error

> does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point

Indicates that you are missing a Main() method in your program.  For example, a console program has

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
    }
}
```

Check the code that is compiled into DO.exe and ensure that you have a Main() method, and that the method is actually being compiled (e.g. not removed with `#if false` or the source file is not set to be compiled).

**UPDATE**

Look at these lines

'C:\Users\Faneela\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\PL\DO\bin\Debug\DO.exe' could not be found Error 6 Metadata file 'C:\Users\Faneela\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\PL\DO\bin\Debug\DO.exe' could not be found Error 7 Metadata file 'c:\users\faneela\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\PL\main\bin\Debug\main.exe'

Visual Studio is trying to compile two .exe files.  I suspect that you intend DO.exe to actually be DO.dll, a class library.  If that is the case, change it's properties accordingly

[image]

Comment: This is the root cause, but the other errors I think may be pretty telling of what is going on here. Looks like the OP is trying to create a class library but the output is set to an executable. The metadata files usually aren't needed unless the project is set as a reference for another one in the same solution in my experience.

Comment: Looking over the output again, I think you're write and I see where.  Updated my answer.